# Finding The Tangent Line Of $y = \sin x$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Hello everyone I have a tangent line with slope $= a$  to $y = \sin x$ in 2 points $(u_1,v_1) , (u_2  ,v_2)$

How can I prove that $\tan a = a$?

My direction was to express $a$ with the points by $a = \frac{u_1-u_2}{v_1-v_2}$

and the tangent line equation is $y = ax -au_1 +v_1$

$f(x) = \sin x  \iff  f'(u) = \cos u$

so $\cos u_1 = a$ and $\cos u_2 = a$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, as there are more solutions.  Let's $(u,\sin(u))$ and $(v,\sin(v))$ be two points. (We exclude the trivial case $v=u+2k\pi$.) The equations of their tangents are
$$
\begin{align}
y-\sin(u)&=\cos(u)(x-u)\\
y-\sin(v)&=\cos(v)(x-v).
\end{align}
$$
We have $\cos(u)=\cos(v)$, which gives $v=2k\pi-u$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$ Furthermore we must have equal $y$-intercepts, that is
$$\sin(u)-u\cos(u)=\sin(v)-v\cos(v).$$
Plugging in $v=2k\pi-u$ and solving for $\tan(u)=\sin(u)/\cos(u)$ finally gives
$$\tan(u)=u+k\pi.$$

Here's an example where $k=5$.

[image]

Comment: I didn't understand why $\sin(u)-u\cos(u)=\sin(v)-v\cos(v)$?

Comment: See my edit, please.

Comment: Now is all clear except why $v = u +2k\pi$?

Comment: Elementary property of $\cos$.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!